# Calculate probability that M out of N events will appear

Tags: algorithm, probability

I have probabilities of 110 independent events. 
I want to calculate for every number of events, that exactly that number of distinct events will appear.

Example, if we have only three events

```
A = 0.45
B = 0.65
C = 0.73

# Probability of none event
P[0] = (1-A)*(1-B)*(1-C)

# Probability of exaclty one event
P[1] = A*(1-B)*(1-C)+(1-A)*B*(1-C)+(1-A)*(1-B)*C

# Probability of exactly two events
P[2] = A*B*(1-C)+A*(1-B)*C+(1-A)*B*C

# Probability of exactly three events
P[3] = A*B*C
```

Is realistic to compute it for 110 events under 1 hour?

If yes, how to do it in any programming language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the probabilities be p_1, p_2, ..., p_n. You're in essence trying to expand the polynomial

```
(1 - p_1 + p_1 x) (1 - p_2 + p_2 x) ... (1 - p_n + p_n x),
```

where the probability of getting m events is the coefficient of x^m. Rather than computing all 2^n monomials and summing them, you can simplify after each multiplication. In Python:

```
def f(ps):
    coefs = [1]
    for p in ps:
        coefs.append(0)
        for i in range(len(coefs) - 1, 0, -1):
            coefs[i] = coefs[i] * (1 - p) + coefs[i - 1] * p
        coefs[0] *= 1 - p
    return coefs
```

Sample execution (note the floating point error).

```
>>> f([0.45, 0.65, 0.73])
[0.05197500000000001, 0.279575, 0.454925, 0.21352500000000002]
```